# Implementing generations in nginx direct memcached cache?

Tags: django, caching, nginx

For my project, I have a cache setup like so: `nginx_cache(60*60)(MyView.as_view())` function sets a key in `memcached` of `nginx./URI`

Nginx looks in memcached for that key before deciding to return a page from cache or send the request to my app. The problem I'm running into is creating cache keys with generations so that I can invalidate groups of keys.

For example, the ideal cache key for me is.... `group_nameX:generationY:URL`.

Nginx would have to figure out the generation key without communicating to the python app.

That leaves me with a contrived idea: Set three cache values via django;

- The group name in a way that can be found by nginx without talking to the app
- The generation number for that particular group name
- The full cache key / output (html page)

On the nginx side, I think I'd need to make use of `LuaModule` and `Memc`. I've never used a non vanilla nginx, so it's best avoided for me but I don't know if I have a choice.

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpLuaModule#ngx.location.capture
http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpMemcModule

I'd need to set up two internal location directives which use Memc to get keys.

My main location directive woud...

- `$genkey set_by_lua` (capture internal location get_key_name)
- `$gen_number set_by_lua` (capture internal location get_key_number_from_name)
- `$memcached_key "$genkey-$gen_number-$request_uri"`

Is there a way to simplify this caching setup? Is there a commonly accepted method I don't know about? (likely - I'm making this up!)

Comment: actually this should be moved to serverfault. oops!

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding what you want but couldn't you just:

1. add a X-Generation (or whatever you want to call it) http headerto the app output
2. then simply set the memcached_key using that value

On the nginx side that would yield something like:

```
location /app/ {
  #add you're normal directives for app calling
  set $memcached_key group_nameX:$sent_http_X_Generation:$request_uri;
}
```

see http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24sent_http_HEADER for more on the variables accessing http response header values

Comment: This is an interesting idea! But if the user never sees the app, it won't ever get new headers. Say it goes from memcached page to memcached page and never communicates with the app. The app still needs to invalidate memcached pages without requiring a request frmomthe client